# Transform seconds in time in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have for example `259201 seconds` in a variable.

How can I transform it in a `"normally"` time like `4 days 00:00:01` ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is very simple to do this in PHP:

```
<?php
$secs = "259201";

$days = gmdate("d", $secs);

$hoursminssecs = gmdate("H:i:s", $secs);

if ($days == 0) { $days = empty($days); } elseif ($days == "1") { $days = "1 day"; } else { $days = $days." days"; }

echo $days." - ".$hoursminssecs
?>
```

Hopes it helps you!